# Make PendingIntent from notification not fire if the Activity is already on front

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

`Service` A creates a `Notification` with a `PendingIntent` that opens `Activity` B. User pulls the notification drawer down and presses the `Notification` with `Activity` B on front previously. The `PendingIntent` basically adds another instance of `Activity` B instead of opening the currently open one.

Is there any way to make the `PendingIntent` open the `Activity` if it's already open, go back on the backstack if there's an instance of that `Activity` there, and open a new instance otherwise?

Comment: its fire but call your onresume methos buddy

Answer (score 2):

Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` when creating the `Intent` for your `Notification`.

Setting both `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` will cause an existing instance of the `Activity` to be used (`onNewIntent()` will be called). If you only specify `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and there is already an existing instance of the `Activity`, that instance (and all other activities on top of it) will be finished and removed from the stack and a **new instance** of the `Activity` will be created (`onCreate()` will be called).

Comment: I was missing the INTENT.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can use the single task or single instance launch mode of your activity (or in your pending intent flags) to control this behavior.

Check the [launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#lmodes) documentation for details on how to set those flags.

Comment: This is a bad idea. These launch modes are only for very special situations (for example: a HOME-Screen replacement). They cause more problems than they solve for most developers. There are other easier ways to do this.

Comment: I guess you didn't see in my answer I said "or in your pending intent flags" - same as your answer.

Comment: Sorry, there are lots of questions on stackoverflow that are answered with "use singleTask/singleInstance launchMode". Nearly all of these are wrong. In almost all cases it is a bad/dangerous suggestion. The fact that you added "or in flags" doesn't really help to answer the question because you would have had to specify which flags to use to get the desired behaviour. I think this answers does more harm than good. I've seen so many developers get lost because someone suggested that they use these special launchModes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Activity's attribute in Manifest file as following:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

or

On defining Flags for PendingIntent, you can use flags as:

```
Intent in=new Intent();
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: Using special launch modes is dangerous and confusing and makes more problems than it solves. Please don't suggest this. It is the wrong approach to solve this problem.